# How to include common xsl file inside other xsl files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I have several xsl files that need to include common xsl file. So instead of including the javascript files in each one of them I would like to create a Common.xsl that will include the java script files and all xsl files will include it. 
The question is how to do that?
I tried some suggested methods using including javascript file but with no success, in the browser console I get errors: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** 

It looks like the jquery was not included.
I tried to do something like this:

> <"script type="text/javascript" src="common.js" /> 
>  
>   or

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
})();
```

Edit:
I answered my question see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by the following code using xsl instead of javascript files:

I have created a Common.xsl file that includes all my common javascript files.

Common.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="Common">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/site.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/common.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/MessagesConstants.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/win_functions.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/resizeFunctions.js"/>
</xsl:template>
```

On every xsl file that need those includes I added the following lines:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:include href="common/Common.xsl"/> <!-- Here I include the Common.xsl -->
   <xsl:template match="/Reflection">
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></xsl:text>
       <html>
           <head>
               <title><xsl:value-of select="Localization/ViewAbout"/></title>

               <xsl:call-template name="Common"/>  <!-- Here I apply the tamplate of the common includes -->

                  <body>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                  </body>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

In order resolve the include URI (**see xsl:include**) in my java application server I had to implement the URIResolver resolve() function:

```
public class XslURIResolver implements URIResolver
{
   private static final String XSL_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separatorChar + INetlayerConstants.c_UI_PATH + INetlayerConstants.c_XSL_PATH;

@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException
{
    DOMSource xslDomSource;
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(XSL_PATH + href);
        InputSource xslInputSource = new InputSource(in);

        Document xslDoc = dBuilder.parse(xslInputSource);
        xslDomSource = new DOMSource(xslDoc);
        xslDomSource.setSystemId(XSL_PATH + href);
        return xslDomSource;
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SAXException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

And then before transformation I set the URIResolver:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tFactory.setURIResolver(new XslURIResolver());
```

That's about it, hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:element name="script">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">common.js</xsl:attribute>
        /* common code */
  </xsl:element>
```

That should do the trick

Comment: But you could use the same approach to directly point to the jquery